# How to access parent's build number in Drone.IO when triggering a forked build using deployment hook?

Tags: drone.io

I'm trying to build a CI pipeline with drone.io.

The steps are:

- Build a docker image
- Tag the docker image with the drone_build_number
- Deploy the image to the staging environment, "ECS, please deploy `myimage:drone_build_number`"

The deployment triggers some tests in the staging environment. If these pass, the drone.io's deployment hook is called: `http://mydronehost/builds/123?fork=true&event=deployment&deploy_to=prod`. This should deploy `myimage:drone_build_number` to prod, where `build_number` was 123 in this case. Instead, the build gets a new number, e.g. 124, and the deployment fails, since `myimage:124` does not exist.

Is it possible to somehow access the "parent" build-number (123) in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not tag the image with the git commit SHA so it'll be consistent between repeated builds of the same release and across environments?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what we ended up doing actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you promote a build you can access the parent build number using the DRONE_BUILD_PARENT environment variable.